# Human Eye Diagram: question about some dimensions

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, vision, eyes, human-eye

Does anyone know any of the answers to these questions about this human eye diagram:

1. What points should be the center of the circle for the radius numbers (Rn) in the following diagram?
2. The difference between the two values R1 and R2?

**My suspicions**: From what I can tell, Cornea R1 refers to the left side (front) of the Cornea measured from the right side (rear) of the Lens at its apex.  I'm not sure why R1 differs from R2.  Lens R1 values represent the lens between its changing diameter when it focuses (due to muscles) and is measured from the center of the largest circle of the eye in this picture.  Again, not sure how R1 differs from R1.  Retina is measured from the center of the largest circle of the eye in this picture.

[image: a]
ref: [reference](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fomlc.org%2Fclassroom%2Foslotut%2Feye%2Fwalker-eye.png&tbnid=m9RPfwWApT51FM&vet=12ahUKEwjYx6X6_I2EAxXQJ2IAHSiRCmIQMygAegQIARBQ..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fomlc.org%2Fclassroom%2Foslotut%2Feye%2Findex.html&docid=bv64kCoiUz6ucM&w=2578&h=1596&q=dimensions%20for%20human%20eye%20lens&client=safari&ved=2ahUKEwjYx6X6_I2EAxXQJ2IAHSiRCmIQMygAegQIARBQ)